# Residual gauge fixing in Lorenz gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge

**Background**

Let $A^{\mu}$ be a 4-potential that satisfies the Lorenz condition
$$\partial_\mu A^\mu =0$$
We can make a gauge transformation $$A_\mu \to A'_\mu=A_\mu + \partial_\mu \Lambda$$
such that
$$
\partial_\mu A'^\mu =\partial_{\mu}\left(A^{\mu}+\partial^{\mu}\Lambda\right)=0
$$
and still stay in the Lorenz gauge. Since $\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}=0$,
this condition for $\Lambda$ is
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\Lambda=0\tag{1}
\end{equation}
This possibility to do some gauge transformations while having fixed the Lorenz condition is called *residual gauge freedom*.

**Claim**

We want to remove this residual gauge freedom by fixing another condition
on $A_{\mu}$. My book claims that
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}A_{3}(0,\vec{x}) & =0\\
\partial_{t}A_{3}(0,\vec{x}) & =0
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
\end{align}
is such a condition.

**Proof**

The solution to (1) is uniquely
determined by its initial conditions
\begin{align*}
\Lambda(0,\vec{x}) & =\Phi_{1}(\vec{x})\\
\partial_{t}\Lambda(0,\vec{x}) & =\Phi_{2}(\vec{x})
\end{align*}
so it is sufficient to prove that the conditions (2) imposed on the
transformed 4-potential uniquely determine $\Phi_{1}$ and $\Phi_{2}$.
Since
$$
A'_{3}=A_{3}+\partial_{3}\Lambda
$$
they read
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A_{3}(0,\vec{x})+\partial_{3}\Lambda(0,\vec{x}) & = & A_{3}(0,\vec{x})+\partial_{3}\Phi_{1}(\vec{x}) & =0\\
\partial_{t}A_{3}(0,\vec{x})+\partial_{t}\partial_{3}\Lambda(0,\vec{x}) & = & \partial_{t}A_{3}(0,\vec{x})+\partial_{t}\partial_{3}\Phi_{2}(\vec{x}) & =0
\end{alignat*}
So we can choose an antiderivative wrt $x^{3}$ of the given
functions $A_{3}(0,\vec{x})$ and $\partial_{t}A_{3}(0,\vec{x})$
to find the $\Lambda$ we're searching for.

**Question**

It seems to me that this antiderivative is not uniquely determined, as you
can add to it an arbitrary function of $x^{1}$ and $x^{2}$. So $\Lambda$
is not uniquely determined either. Is then the residual gauge not
removed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Which book? Which page? Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190001/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that this question is answered there. That question is answered by the fact that the Lorenz gauge gives the possibility of a residual gauge. In this case, this fact is the *background* for the question, which is about how to actually fix the residual gauge.

Comment: Book is Elettrodinamica Classica by Kurt Lechner and is only available in italian AFAIK.

Comment: Link to abstract page? Which page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which link you want me to post, but this is a link to the book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9788847052109 and the page is 137.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that you can add a function of $\lambda(x,y)$ to your gauge parameter. But note that it should satisfy the Lorenz gauge which implies that
$$(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2)\lambda=0$$
whose general solutions consists of arbitrary holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions on the plane $$\lambda=f(z)+g(\bar z), \qquad z=x+i y,\quad \bar z =x-iy$$
The point is that this solution diverges somewhere. Expanding $f=\sum_n c_n (z-z_0)^n$ we see that the function diverges either at $z=z_0$ or at $z\to \infty$ except for the constant function.

Imposing some boundary conditions, say $A_\mu\sim\cal{O}(1/r)$ on the gauge field at $r=\sqrt{x^+y^2+z^2} \to \infty$ and requiring smoothness of the gauge field in the bulk of spacetime excludes the additional freedom you mentioned.

There is however a nice story about *asymptotic symmetries* surviving gauge fixing and boundary conditions which is not necessary for your question here.